# print list x times and change its elements python

Tags: python, list

I've been struggling about this example in Python. 
I have a list which consists of some text:
x = ["line1\n","line2\n","line3\n"]
then I want to modify its elements and print the list 3 times. This is my code now:

```
for y in range(3):
    for n,i in enumerate(x):
        if i == 'line1\n':
            x[n] = 'line1' + str(y) + '\n'
        if i == 'line2\n':
            x[n] = 'line2' + str(y) + '\n'
        if i == 'line3\n':
            x[n] = 'line3' + str(y) + '\n'
    print(''.join(x))
```

This gives me:

line10

line20

line30

3 times. But what I want to get is:

line10

line20

line30

then

line11

line21

line31

etc

Do you know how can I get this result? What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: You should append `str(n)` to `linex`. But what are you trying to solve?

Comment: I don't want to append. I have to modify the elements. This program above its just an example what I want to archive. My program is much more complex.

Comment: you have to create a new string and can't modify an existing one since strings are immutable. Please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your enumeration runs through correctly the first time, and changes all the lines to

```
 x[0] = line10\n
 x[1] = line20\n
 x[2] = line30\n
```

Then your if statements no longer apply. They're still looking for `if x[0] == 'line1\n':` but now `x[0] = line10\n`

Can you not try checking them by their position in the array like so?

```
for y in range(3):
    for n in enumerate(x):
        if n == 0
            x[n] = 'line1' + str(y) + '\n'
        if n == 1
            x[n] = 'line2' + str(y) + '\n'
        if n == 2
            x[n] = 'line3' + str(y) + '\n'
    print(''.join(x))
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I knew it can be done :)  Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for y in range(3):
    for n,i in enumerate(x):
        if i == 'line1\n':
            x[n] = 'line1' + str(y) + '\n'
        if i == 'line2\n':
            x[n] = 'line2' + str(y) + '\n'
        if i == 'line3\n':
            x[n] = 'line3' + str(y) + '\n'
```

will set each line to be

`x[n] = 'line1' + 0 + '\n'`,

`x[n] = 'line2' + 0 + '\n'`,

`x[n] = 'line3' + 0 + '\n'`

Then when you loop back a second time none of the lines will meet the conditions you're checking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right on what you are trying to achieve, this is the solution:

I changed the `str(y)` to `str(n)` wich was the source of the wrong counting.

```
x = ["line1\n", "line2\n", "line3\n"]

for n, i in enumerate(x):
    if i == 'line1\n':
        x[n] = 'line1' + str(n) + '\n'
    if i == 'line2\n':
        x[n] = 'line2' + str(n) + '\n'
    if i == 'line3\n':
        x[n] = 'line3' + str(n) + '\n'

for y in range(3):
    print(''.join(x))
```

But this code does not make much sense as I do not know the context, so this may not be what you wanted.